# writing null space basis in MATLAB without using null(A)

Tags: matlab, matrix, null, space

My teacher wants us to find the basis of the null space of a function in MATLAB. This is the exact question.

Use the MATLAB function rref and the function lead above to write a MATLAB
`function N=nullbase(A)` which computes a matrix N whose columns form a basis
for the nullspace of A. Your file nullbase.m should not use the MATLAB functions
`rank` or `null`.

Please someone help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the SVD (singular value decomposition). Because this sounds like a homework problem, I won't give away the whole answer, but this hint should help. MATLAB has an SVD function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/svd.html